# How do I limit 3g speed on my Nexus One

Tags: 3g

I have 1gb of traffic per month. Internet speed is 2.2mbits, so it's pretty easy to waste all gb in a few days. I don't usually watch youtube from my phone, and 500-700 kbits would be pretty enough for me. Is there an application or way I can manually limit 3g speed manually, without rooting the phone?

Answer (score 3):

If all else fails, you could set the “Use only 2G networks” option...

Comment: Well that's too slow and doesn't worth it. But thanks)

Answer (score 1):

3G Watchdog is capable, when coupled with APNdroid or JuiceDefender, to automatically disable mobile internet connections when you reach a configurable % of your quota.

Answer (score -1):

Try [NetSentry](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.netsentry) or [3G Watchdog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdog).

Comment: I use 3g watchdog and NetCounter, but these only collect data about traffic, don't limit it in any way.

Comment: Did you try Netsentry? It doesn't limit traffic but can notify when limits are reached.

Comment: Apps which I use have this function too and much more. Thanks anyway)